# Why do we update $W$ with $\frac{1}{\mu (A_t | S_t)}$ instead of $\frac{\pi (A_t | S_t)}{\mu (A_t | S_t)}$ in off-policy Monte Carlo control?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-methods

I had the same question when I am reading the RL textbook from Sutton Bartol [as posted here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/38341/34637).

[image]

Why do we update $W$ with $\frac{1}{\mu (A_t | S_t)}$ instead of $\frac{\pi (A_t | S_t)}{\mu (A_t | S_t)}$?

It seems that, with the updating rule from the textbook, whatever action $\mu$ decides to choose, we automatically assume that $\pi$ will choose it with 100% probability. But $\pi$ is greedy with respect to Q. How does this assumption make sense?

Comment: It says there that $\pi$ is a deterministic policy

Comment: Ah I see! It could be 0 but in case of 0, loop already breaks before updating W. Should have read the algorithms a few more times. Thank you very much!